# Want to enter a text into textbox using VBA

Tags: input

want to enter a text into texbox where the tag is input tag, it has ID as well

i am using ie.document.getElementsById("myId").Value = "newtext"

however its giving an error "object doesn't support this property or method"

please give resolution

Comment: Why the `s`? `getElementsById` => `getElementById`

Comment: Thanks John, that was my bad..now its working

Comment: It would help if Microsoft had consistent naming conventions `getElementsByID` is wrong but `getElementsByName` is right

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it like this. The best way to set the value is to add the attribute "value" to the element:

Example:

```
ie.document.getElementsById("myId").setAttribute("value", "newtext");
```

That should work.